# Nodejs passing callback variable issue

Tags: node.js

Am trying to pass the two variables below: `curr_output` & `max_output`
to `res.render` but getting `"undefined"` error.

```js
function getCurDepth(callback) {
  var child = cp.exec(bash.cmd_2, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    global.curr_output = stdout.split(/[\r\n|\n|\r]/).filter(String);
    callback(curr_output);
    //return curr_output;
  });
}

function getMaxDepth(callback) {
  var child = cp.exec(bash.cmd_3, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    global.max_output = stdout.split(/[\r\n|\n|\r]/).filter(String);
    callback(max_output);
    //return max_output;
  });
}

getCurDepth(function(curr_output) {
  console.log(`CURDEPTH is: ${QMGR}_${APP_ID}_${QUEUE}_${curr_output}`);
});

getMaxDepth(function(max_output) {
  console.log(`MAXQDEPTH is: ${QMGR}_${APP_ID}_${QUEUE}_${max_output}`);
});

res.render("qdepth", {
  data: {
    qmgr: QMGR,
    app_id: APP_ID,
    queue: QUEUE,
    curdepth: curr_output,
    maxqdepth: max_output,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@Nikhil Baliga already gave you one possible source of trouble in your code, but the bigger issue lies in understanding the Node execution model.

The child processes run asynchronously, which means they run out-of-line. This is also why you need a callback to get the final result. Since they don't block the main thread, and might not finish and invoke the callback function before your call to render executes, it means that the variables you're trying to read from haven't necessarily been assigned a value yet.

To solve your problem, you need to defer calling render up until both of the child processes have completed and invoked their respective callbacks. For this you either need to nest the calls, which mean they happen sequentially, which inevitably will be slower than your current parallel approach, or you need to orchestrate the jobs somehow.

For managing parallel jobs, you will probably want to use something like the [async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module, but for the learning experience, you might want to initially try and write the necessary code for yourself.

However, to directly answer your question, you will need something akin to this to get the job done:

```js
function getCurDepth(callback) {
  var child = cp.exec(bash.cmd_2, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    let curr_output = stdout.split(/[\r\n|\n|\r]/).filter(String);
    callback(curr_output);
  });
}

function getMaxDepth(callback) {
  var child = cp.exec(bash.cmd_3, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    let max_output = stdout.split(/[\r\n|\n|\r]/).filter(String);
    callback(max_output);
  });
}

let render_params = {
  // We need to keep track of how many of the jobs have finished
  pendingJobs: 2,
  curDepth: undefined,
  maxDepth: undefined,
};

function render({ pendingJobs, curDepth, maxDepth }) {
  if (pendingJobs > 0) {
    // If there are still unfinished tasks, don't render yet
    return;
  }

  res.render("qdepth", {
    data: {
      qmgr: QMGR,
      app_id: APP_ID,
      queue: QUEUE,
      curdepth: curDepth,
      maxqdepth: maxDepth,
    },
  });
}

getCurDepth(function(curr_output) {
  console.log(`CURDEPTH is: ${QMGR}_${APP_ID}_${QUEUE}_${curr_output}`);

  render_params.pendingJobs--;
  render_params.curDepth = curr_output;
  render(render_params);
});

getMaxDepth(function(max_output) {
  console.log(`MAXQDEPTH is: ${QMGR}_${APP_ID}_${QUEUE}_${max_output}`);

  render_params.pendingJobs--;
  render_params.maxDepth = max_output;
  render(render_params);
});
```

This is a "quick-n-dirty" method of getting it over the line and it's certainly very "hacky", but it demonstrates the challenges in keeping track of jobs and knowing when the program can carry on.

A more idiomatic and elegant solution is to use [Promises](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/promise). (A Promise represents a future value, and it's a great tool in async programming.) Using promises, the code would become something like this:

```js
function getCurDepth(callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var child = cp.exec(bash.cmd_2, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      let curr_output = stdout.split(/[\r\n|\n|\r]/).filter(String);
      resolve(curr_output);
    });
  });
}

function getMaxDepth() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    var child = cp.exec(bash.cmd_3, function(error, stdout, stderr) {
      let max_output = stdout.split(/[\r\n|\n|\r]/).filter(String);
      resolve(max_output);
    });
  });
}

Promise.all([getCurDepth(), getMaxDepth()]).then(([curDepth, maxDepth]) => {
  res.render("qdepth", {
    data: {
      qmgr: QMGR,
      app_id: APP_ID,
      queue: QUEUE,
      curdepth: curDepth,
      maxqdepth: maxDepth,
    },
  });
});
```

To cover your bases further, you would probably want to also have a fail-safe, which will render an error page if any job fails to finish within a set time. For this, look at [`setTimeout`](https://devdocs.io/node/timers#timers_settimeout_callback_delay_args).

For reading reading up on asynchronous programming, check out [Understanding Async Programming in Node.js](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/). If you want to learn more about the event loop, the presentation [In The Loop](https://youtu.be/cCOL7MC4Pl0) by Jake Archibald might be a good watch.

To gain more insight into node and its programming model, maybe have a look at Nodeschool's [Learn You Node](https://github.com/workshopper/learnyounode) workshopper.

Comment: It looks like I missed async running not being handled while reading the code :)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting value to the global (`global.curr_output`), but passing just the variable (`curr_output`) which is not set. Either set values without global or pass with global.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for that.

so console.log works:

```
console.log(`CURDEPTH is: ${QMGR}_${APP_ID}_${QUEUE}_${curr_output}`);
```

and no more errors for the res.render:

```
res.render('qdepth',{ data: {qmgr: QMGR, app_id: APP_ID, queue: QUEUE, curdepth: global.curr_output, maxqdepth: global.max_output}});
```

But  qdepth.ejs is not capturing the values: global.curr_output & global.max_output

```
   Curdepth : <input type="number" name="curdepth"
                value='<%= data.curdepth %>'> <br>

  MaxQDepth : <input type="number" name="maxdepth"
                value='<%= data.maxqdepth %>'> <br>
```

Any ideas ?? Thnx again.